# How to check if a two digit array is identical to a certain section of an object array?

Tags: javascript

How do I check if the array in 'playerChoices' equals, let's say, index 0 in 'test1' array. This is my code as of now. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
var playerChoices = [1, 3];
const test1 = [{right: 1, wrong: 3}, {right: 2, wrong: 1}, {right: 3, wrong: 2}];

  function check() {
       for (var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
          if (test1[i] !== playerChoices[i]) return false;
    }
      return true;
    };

  if(check()){
       console.log('true');
    };
```

Comment: an integer will never equal an object literal

Comment: test1[i] returns an object you have to select test1[i].right or test1[i].wrong to select a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return `false` inside the loop, it will always return `false` if the first item does not meet the requirements.

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of them is *equal* as followings:

```js
const test1 = [{right:1,wrong:3},{right:2,wrong:1},{right:3,wrong:2}];

function check(playerChoices) {

  // You can use destructuring here to have a more readable code
  [playerRight, playerWrong] = playerChoices
  
  return test1.some(choice => choice.right === playerRight && choice.wrong === playerWrong)
};

console.log(check([1, 3]))
console.log(check([1, 4]))
```

Comment: is 'choice =>' a short way of writing 'function(choice){}'?

Comment: It is called `arrow function`, another way to write functions. You can have a look at this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Why did you use destructuring for 'playerChoices'? Can't I just compare 'choice' with each index in 'playerChoices'? For example: choice.right === playerChoices[0] && choice.wrong === playerChoices[1]

Comment: Of course you can compare it. I added destructuring just because I think it is more readable but it changes from person to person.